How to convert SearchCallback String into string in Dart
I am working on Dart/Flutter SearchCallback property.
I need to convert SearchCallback<String?> into String.
The SearchCallback has a function example.
The function example returns integer index.
In DropdownMenu class, I need to use SearchCallback<String?>.
To use SearchCallback function example, I need to specify function return as: SearchCallback<String?>
I don't know how to create this return type.
Therefore, I need to convert SearchCallback<String?> into String.
Could you please explain how to do this conversion.
my code:
int index1=0;

  SearchCallback<String?> xp(List<DropdownMenuEntry<Text>> entries,String a){
    if (a.isNotEmpty) {
     index1 = entries.indexWhere((DropdownMenuEntry<Text> entry) => entry.label == a);
      return index1 != -1 ? index1 : null;
  }

Thank You

I dont know if I understood your question so sorry if is the case.
Do you wish to get the result in string format?
See the code below if it will works for you.
While you are typing it will print the value.
      DropdownMenu<Text>(
        enableSearch: true,
        searchCallback: (List<DropdownMenuEntry<Text>> entries, String query) {
          if (query.isEmpty) {
            return null;
          }
          
          print(query);//Here will print what we are typing in the field
          
          final int index = entries.indexWhere((DropdownMenuEntry<Text> entry) => entry.label == query);

          return index != -1 ? index : null;
        },
        dropdownMenuEntries: ['x1','x2','x3','x4','x5'].map<DropdownMenuEntry<Text>>(
              (String txt) {
            return DropdownMenuEntry<Text>(
              value: Text(txt),
              label: txt,
            );
          },
        ).toList(),
      ),


Hello! Please see above.
